# After validating a column a button change

Tags: jsf, datatable

I'm working with JSF2. I have a datatable. For making the example easier let's assume, that I have two columns in each row:

- Input field
- Button

If the Input field changed, I want to change the text of the button, without any request to the server.

Till this time for changing values I used js. Though in this case I am not sure how to connect the two columns without an id, and I also do not know how to generate an Id, which can be used, because I can not use varStatus.

I'm new to JSF so sorry, if it is something trivial, I did not found the solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to fire a request, you can do this purely in javascript. 
Write a function that changes the text of the button, then call it from your onchange attribute in the inputfield. This only changes the text when the inputfield loses focus though. If you want to change the text when you type something, you could register the function to the keydown and keyup attributes of the inputfield.

Comment: Thanks, I just do not understand, how to register the js code to the exact button, which have to be modified. (I always just want to change the one, which is in the same row). Because I do not have any ids.

Comment: You could generate an id for the button based on the item var in the datatable i.e. value=#{controller.items} var=#{item} for the datatable and <button id="button#{item.id}"/> inside the row. After that you can just <input onchange="alterButton('button#{item.id}')".

Comment: Thanks, that was my only idea as well, I just did not want to write a function to generate an id, because I do not have anything really sensible to use as one.